# Horse Racing in Halacha

Tags: halacha, shabbat, sport-athletics, hanaah-benefit, gambling

I have been doing some reading and I see some pages which say that horse racing is frowned upon by halacha (but without sources) as running afoul of tza'ar ba'alei chayim (a comment [here](http://osdir.com/ml/culture.religion.jewish.avodah/2006-07/msg00069.html), and [here](https://www.facebook.com/halachickashrus/posts/476615809066305), and a statement [here](http://www.icjudaism.org.uk/ethics.html)).

Other sources look at the gambling aspect of it, or the lack of [usefulness](http://travelingrabbi.com/halacha-general/the-jewish-view-on-gambling-betting-horse-racing-and-the-melbourne-cup) of [watching](http://www.revach.net/article.php?id=4045) it and some discuss [rulings](http://www.chai-online.org/en/campaigns/racing/media/psak_hazofe.htm) against actually holding races.

I am wondering if there is any additional concern regarding owning a race horse - if I don't bet on the race or attend it, can I benefit from the event? And additionally, if the event is on Shabbos, can I benefit from it? Note, I own no animals so this is a theoretical exercise for me regarding the application of halacha.

Comment: Two separate questions here; horse racing in Halacha and benefiting from Shabbat events.

Comment: I assume Ahmed Zayat's Derby win is on your mind... :)

Comment: @shman613 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16722/can-one-take-any-money-offered-to-him